# WPF Toolkit - Deactivate Chart Animation

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

When a new Chart is created and a Series (ColumnSeries for example) is added along with data the columns are rendered as a type of FadeIn animation and appear a split second after the Chart is drawn on screen.

Is there anyway to stop this animation happening? Alternatively, is there anyway of forcing the chart to complete the animations before rendering?

Paul

Answer (score 1):

i have downloaded the latest source code at http://wpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

my idea is, to remove the animation by changing the style for the different chart series (chart points, DataPointStyle)

example for `charting:PieDataPoint`

try to remove the animation for the shown data and take your own style with a given key (x:key="myStyle" -> `DataPointStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}"`)

and remove `Opacity="0"` at `<Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="0">`

remove this visual state group from your style

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="RevealStates">
    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualState x:Name="Shown">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Hidden">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0" />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

**EDIT**

This is the changed style.

```
<!--  charting:PieDataPoint  -->
<Style TargetType="charting:PieDataPoint">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="RatioStringFormat" Value="{}{0:p2}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:PieDataPoint">
                <Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="0">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverHighlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.6" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionHighlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.6" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Path x:Name="Slice" Data="{TemplateBinding Geometry}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeMiterLimit="1">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" />
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedRatio}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    </Path>
                    <Path x:Name="SelectionHighlight" Data="{TemplateBinding GeometrySelection}" Fill="Red" StrokeMiterLimit="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" />
                    <Path x:Name="MouseOverHighlight" Data="{TemplateBinding GeometryHighlight}" Fill="White" StrokeMiterLimit="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

After my first attempt to remove the animation, I wanted to give up, because it has not worked.

But then I looked upon me with the reflector to the source code and have found a way that it still works.

Setting the DataPointStyle unfortunately is not enough, I think it's a bug.

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Margin="8">

  <chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
    <chartingToolkit:BarSeries x:Name="barSeries"
                                Title="Experience"
                                DataPointStyle="{StaticResource myBarStyle}">
    </chartingToolkit:BarSeries>
  </chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>

</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

In the constructor of the control where the chart is included simply execute the following.

```
this.barSeries.RefreshStyles();
```

hope this helps